# Why was my Destiny 2 drop such a low level?

Tags: destiny-2

I was playing through a Strike with a friend today and I got this drop.[image: 10 Defense Item]

Even though my power level is 251, the defense on this piece of armor was only 10. It had good stats, but I don't understand why the defense is so low.

Comment: Did you get this as an actual drop, or from a Bright Engram?

Comment: I believe it was a regular drop, not an engram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Destiny wiki](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Armor_Sets#Omega_Mechanos_.28Season_2_Eververse.29_Armor_Sets) classifies Omega Mechanos as Season 2 Eververse armor set; Season 1 being the Optimacy armor set. When searching for these pieces of gear on DestinyTracker, [Optimacy](https://db.destinytracker.com/d2/en/items/armor?q=Optimacy&t=5) and [Omega Mechanos](https://db.destinytracker.com/d2/en/items/armor?q=Omega&t=5), they are shown with a 10 defense when acquired.

According to users on reddit, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/destiny2/comments/7i0kqf/omega_mechanos_gloves/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/destiny2/comments/78xb6d/whats_the_purpose_of_these_10_defense_and_i_got/), Eververse armor sets are design to always be dropped at 10 defense regardless of your current defense level or how you obtain it. This is speculated to prevent a *pay-to-win* status, since Bright/Illuminated Engrams can be purchased with real currency

Comment: Ah it looks like I could have saved it to infuse later. Thanks!